# c# Ext .net ComboBox

Tags: c#, email, model-view-controller, combobox, ext.net

I need to know if I can do this:

I have a combobox with the email addresses. The problem is, when I select an email or various emails, the box looks like this:

[image]

I want to know if I can add a button behind the emails because I want to add a button (a button who delete the email) behind the email, like this
[image]

@pagep Helped me so much, but I made a mistake writing the tags, I wrote extjs and this is not extjs, this is ext.net mvc.

This can be adding a `tagfield`, but I don't know how to implement in my project.

I'm going to complete this question adding the source code where I want to implement this.

```
Html.X().ComboBoxFor(m => m.LST_CONTACTO_ASOCIADO_RECEPTOR)
                                .ID("LST_CONTACTO_ASOCIADO_RECEPTOR")
                                .Editable(false)
                                .FieldLabel("Destinatario *")
                                .DisplayField("DE_EMAIL")
                                .ValueField("ID_CONTACTO")
                                .MultiSelect(true)
                                .Flex(1)

                                .MsgTarget(MessageTarget.Under)
                                .TypeAhead(false)
                                .ListConfig(Html.X().BoundList()
                                    .LoadingText("Buscando...")
                                    .ItemTpl(Html.X().XTemplate()
                                        .Html(
                                        @<text>
                                            <div class="search-item-nombre">
                                                {DE_APELLIDOS}, {DE_NOMBRE}
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="search-item-mail">
                                                {DE_EMAIL}
                                            </div>
                                        </text>
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                                .Store(
                                    Html.X().Store()
                                        .Model(
                                            Html.X().Model()
                                                .IDProperty("ID_CONTACTO")
                                                .Fields(
                                                    Html.X().ModelField().Name("ID_CONTACTO"),
                                                    Html.X().ModelField().Name("DE_NOMBRE"),
                                                    Html.X().ModelField().Name("DE_APELLIDOS"),
                                                    Html.X().ModelField().Name("DE_DNI"),
                                                    Html.X().ModelField().Name("DE_EMAIL")
                                                )
                                        )
                                        .Proxy(
                                            Html.X().AjaxProxy()
                                                .Url(Url.Content("~/User/ListAgenda"))
                                                .Reader(Html.X().JsonReader().RootProperty("data"))
                                        )
                                        .Listeners(ls =>
                                        {
                                            ls.Load.Fn = "st_destinatario_load";
                                        })
                                        .ShowWarningOnFailure(false)
                                        .AutoLoad(true)
                                )
                                .Listeners(ls =>
                                {
                                    ls.TriggerClick.Handler = "this.removeByValue(this.getValue());this.clearValue();";
                                }),
```

This code is the combobox that appears in the pictures and I want to change it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that best way would be to use `tagfield`:

http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#form-tag

[image: tag field example]

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Tag.html

Comment: i edited my question, let me know if you can help me

Comment: I see, sorry I don't know ext.net so I can't help much :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Html.X().TagField()**, like suggested by @pagep! There's not a **TagFieldFor()** but all you would need is probably:

```
Html.X().TagField().Items(Model.LST_CONTACTO_ASOCIADO_RECEPTOR)
```

Unfortunately there's no TagField example using MVC RazorView syntax in Ext.NET MVC examples explorer, but I could find a good MVC example in this forum post: https://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?28078&p=125105&#post125105

Several examples (in WebForms format) can be found on WebForms Examples Explorer, which can be just the thought you needed before using the component in MVC Razor (porting over should be straightforward). Here's the examples link: http://examples4.ext.net/#/Form/Tag/TagField/